# How to implement passport oauth2 to authenticate rest api using nodejs, mongodb with express framework

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am new in nodejs. I am trying to implement oauth2 with rest api using nodejs, mongodb and express framework. Please suggest me how to implement step by step. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) with the [oauth2 strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2#readme)